# Ilogger is logging to Live Metrics but not to transaction search

Tags: c#, azure, azure-application-insights, ilogger

The problem is as simple:

I am looking to log messages to Azure Transaction Search, when my `Azure Function` is published. I am using Ilogger to do this.

I have managed to connect Application Insight, and log different things in Transaction Search, see picture below:
[image: Transaction Search]

Here, some of the logging is happening, but not all. I am missing my custom traces that I need to log. But the traces are logged in Live Metrics, see picture below: (This is from Live Metrics):

[image: Live Metrics]

Note that my Function does **not** use `Startup.cs` or `IServiceCollection`, I am only using `ApplicationInsight` and `Ilogger` to log.

Code:

```
[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(AFLeaderListFunc.Startup))]

namespace AFLeaderListFunc
{
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Services.AddLogging();
            builder.Services.AddTransient<Function1>();
        }
    }
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        public Function1(ILogger<Function1> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }


        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public async Task Run([TimerTrigger("0 05 13 * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer)
        {
            try
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("Test using DI injection");
                _logger.LogInformation(await GetADUserAsyncByEmail());
                _logger.LogInformation("Executing complete");
                _logger.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation(ex.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
        }
```

As I have multiple methods in my Function I will need to have the `Ilogger` in my constructor, and I believe this creates the issue, as if I call it as a parameter in a method, it can log it correctly.

Any ideas why this is not working or anytihng I should look into?

Thanks ahead.

**Edit**

I also wanted to share my .csproj in case that would be any interrest:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v3</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Identity" Version="1.8.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets" Version="4.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Dapper" Version="2.0.123" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights" Version="2.20.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.15.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.AzureKeyVault.HostingStartup" Version="2.0.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets" Version="3.1.32" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Graph" Version="4.52.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="3.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient" Version="4.8.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Text.Encodings.Web" Version="6.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <FunctionsPreservedDependencies Include="System.Text.Encodings.Web.dll" />
    </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="appsettings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
```

And for my config files, there is nothing related to the Application Insight as to configure logging or something regarding the problem.

Comment: Please share your Configuration and `.csproj` file `file`.

Comment: What is the framework of your Azure Function.

Comment: @Harshitha I have added the relevant things in my question. :)

Comment: `there is nothing related to the Application Insight as to configure logging`, you need to provide the application insights instrumentation key/ connection string in the local.settings.json file

Comment: If you want to log the traces by using the ILogger withut passing the parameter to the function, then you need to use the startup file.But you have mentioend you are not using the startup file.

Comment: Even Iam getting logs only if I add `ILogger` in the Function.

Comment: Please refer similar code in [GitHub](https://gist.github.com/nareshnagpal06/82c6b4df2a987087425c32adb58312c2)